# redirect path with sample README file

Tags: php, config

BELOW is the README file provided by developer:-

I am trying to install in subfolder of my domain directory by name php4dvd,i will be accessing with ex : `www.php4dvd.mydomain.com` " please let me know where should i fillout `"php4dvd"` in below configuration file "**config.inc**"

/**
 * The location of php4dvd on your domain. This property sets itself automatically, but if it fails,
 * you can overwrite it manuall. If you run php4dvd on www.mydomain.com, leave this property empty.
 * If you run php4dvd on `www.mydomain.com/php4dvd/`, please fill out `'php4dvd'`.
 */

```
$baseurl = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$baseurl = preg_replace("/^\//", "", $baseurl);
$baseurl = preg_replace("/\?.*/", "", $baseurl);
$baseurl = preg_replace("/\/install\/?/i", "", $baseurl);
$settings["url"]["base"] = $baseurl;
```

Comment: this has to do with webserver configuration not htaccess rules

Comment: where should i fill out php4dvd in the above lines..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get php4dvd.domain.com to work you will need edit your websites DNS. You can point php4dvd.domain.com to a specific folder (or another webserver if you wish). This will need to be changed in your webservers DNS manager.

You can then point traffic to this domain. The instructions above the code you have supplied do not make much sense. However it does seem to suggest that if your URL is php4dvd.domain.com it should work.